# Prove that there exists $a \in \mathbb{R}$, such that set $\{a+x: x\in K\}$ is included in set of irrational numbers.

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

Let $K$ be closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with empty interior.
Prove that there exists $a \in \mathbb{R}$, such that set $\{a+x: x\in K\}$ is included in set of irrational numbers.

Well, I know that Baire theorem is what should solve that problem. My problems stem from that I am confused how $K$ can look like. Surely we cannot have all irrational numbers included in it. But can we have countably many of them? I suspect we cannot, probably because it would contradict with the fact (no ontological obligations here) that it has empty interior. But what are implications, if any, of that?

Comment: Don't care about how $K$ can look like. It can look very very complicated. Suppose $(a + K) \cap \mathbb{Q} \neq \varnothing$ for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Try to massage that into something you can apply Baire to.

Comment: As a note, $\Bbb{Z}\subset\Bbb{R}$ is closed and has empty interior, and is countably infinite.

Comment: What do you mean by "ontological obligations"?

Comment: Well, probably it was unprofessional to write that. I meant that there are no ontological facts about mathematics. It is only game with symbols.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your intuition is incorrect. $K$ *can* contain infinitely many - even uncountably many! - irrationals and still be a closed set with empty interior (and I'm not sure what "ontological obligations" means in this context).

For an example of a closed set with empty interior containing infinitely many irrationals, consider $\{z+\pi: z\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. This can be modified to be *compact*, in addition, without much effort.

For an example of a closed set with empty interior containing *uncountably many* irrationals, think of the Cantor set - although note that it *also* contains lots of rationals. Coming up with a closed set with empty interior containing uncountably many irrationals *and not containing any rationals* is a harder task, which I leave as an exercise.

---

For solving the problem, here's a hint: for $q\in\mathbb{Q}$, let $A_q=\{r\in\mathbb{R}: q\not\in K+r\}$. Then:

- How many sets of the form $A_q$ are there?
- What kind of set, *topologically*, is $A_q$ (open? closed? neither?)? *Use the fact that $K$ is closed.*
- What kind of set, *distribution-wise*, is $A_q$ (dense? not dense? nowhere dense?)? *Use the fact that $K$ has empty interior.*
- Finally, what does the Baire category theorem say about $\bigcap A_q$, and how does that solve your problem?

Comment: Not to take to much steps at one time. I believe that $A_q$ is open and dense. Am I right?

Comment: @SekstusEmpiryk: Yes, that’s correct.

Comment: So $\mathbb{R}\setminus A_q$ is closed Baire's first category set and from Baire theorem $\bigcup_{q\in\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{R}\setminus A_q$ is also closed first category set. And from that follows that $\bigcap A_q$ is not empty and it conatins all numbers needed to solve my problem. Is it correct?

Comment: @SekstusEmpiryk Yes. (In my opinion, a slightly more intuitive way to think of BCT is "The intersection of countably many open dense sets is nonempty.")